# How can DejaDup backup folders requiring root permissions?

Tags: permissions, backup, deja-dup

I'm using `etckeeper` to manage `/etc` and `Deja-Dup` for `/home`. I wanted to back up `/etc/.git/` as well, using `Deja-Dup`, but this folder has owner:group set to `root:root`. Obviously, running `Deja-Dup` as my user fails to touch it.

I configured `Deja-Dup` from system settings, and I found no option that would help me tackle this there. Any ideas? Or do I go to `duplicity` and run it from `cron`? If so, where can I see what exact calls to `duplicity` are made from `Deja-Dup` (is there anything clearer than setting a debug flag as in `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup` and hunting for calls in wall-of-text that follows)?

I would like to avoid changing the permissions to my user, if possible (I believe etckeeper folks did this under root:root for a reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to include such directories in a backup as long as your user can READ the files (users can often, but not always, read root-owned files).

But if your user can't read the files, I recommend running duplicity directly via cron. Deja Dup is designed for users, not system administrators.

Comment: Design remark really drives home the whole point. I've arrived at same conclusion after few days of searches through options. :-) Thank you Michael!